# PHP mysql display 4 results in one goal

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display the result in the PDF file. The problem now is the PDF file only can catch the first row of the while loop. Is there something like `row[0]['rates']` for the first row and `row[1]['rates']` for the second row? So I can just fetch it once and display `row[0]['rates']` and `row[1]['rates']`...

**Create PDF:**

```
<?php
session_start();

if( empty( $_POST['compare'] ) ) 
include"connect_to_mysql.php";
$packages = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM package_creation WHERE id IN (". implode(',', $_POST['compare']) ." ) LIMIT 4"); 

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($packages)){
 $compare ='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Compare Packages</title>
<style type="text/css">
.print_title{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000; 
}
.print_text{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#000000;
}
.print_bold{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.print_footer{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:9px;
    color:#000000;
}
.print_big{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
body{
    margin:0px;
}
table td{
    height:1px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table class="print_text" align="left">
<tr>
<td width="200px" class="print_bold" align="right">Package</td><td width="100px" class="print_bold" align="center">Package 1</td><td width="100px" class="print_bold" align="center">Package 2</td><td width="100px" class="print_bold" align="center">Package 3</td><td width="100px" class="print_bold" align="center">Package 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="print_bold" align="right">Bank Code:</td><td width="100px" align="center">'.$row['bank_name'].'</td><td width="100px" align="center">display 2nd bank</td><td width="100px" align="center">display 3rd bank</td><td width="100px" align="center">display 4th bank</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';

}
include_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($compare);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('Compare_Packages.pdf');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your while loop. You're overwriting the value of $compare everytime it loops through. What you would want to do is something like

```
 $compare = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Compare Packages</title>
<style type="text/css">
....//you styles here
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table class="print_text" align="left">
<tr>
<td width="200px" class="print_bold" align="right">Package</td><td width="100px"  class="print_bold" align="center">Package 1</td><td width="100px" class="print_bold" align="center">Package 2</td><td width="100px" class="print_bold" align="center">Package 3</td><td width="100px" class="print_bold" align="center">Package 4</td>
</tr>';

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($packages)){

    $compare .= '<tr>
 <td class="print_bold" align="right">Bank Code:</td><td width="100px" align="center">'.$row['bank_name'].'</td><td width="100px" align="center">display 2nd bank</td><td width="100px" align="center">display 3rd bank</td><td width="100px" align="center">display 4th bank</td>
</tr>';
} //end while

$compare .= '</table>
 </body>
  </html>';


//rest of your code
```

This way it adds the results of the loop to the middle of the $compare string rather than overwriting it each time. Look up string concatenation for more details http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php . Apologies if there are any minor code issues here as it's untested

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a whole new document inside the while loop, you can just loop on the table row:

First setup your $compare variable (Notice `[TABLE_ROWS]` inside the string variable $compare):

```
$compare = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Compare Packages</title>
<style type="text/css">
.print_title{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000; 
}
.print_text{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#000000;
}
.print_bold{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.print_footer{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:9px;
    color:#000000;
}
.print_big{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
body{
    margin:0px;
}
table td{
    height:1px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table class="print_text" align="left">
<tr>
<td width="200px" class="print_bold" align="right">Package</td><td width="100px" class="print_bold" align="center">Package 1</td><td width="100px" class="print_bold" align="center">Package 2</td><td width="100px" class="print_bold" align="center">Package 3</td><td width="100px" class="print_bold" align="center">Package 4</td>
</tr>
[TABLE_ROWS]
</table>
</body>
</html>';
```

Then get all the rows to display:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($packages)){
$table_rows .= '<tr>
<td class="print_bold" align="right">Bank Code:</td><td width="100px" align="center">'.$row['bank_name'].'</td><td width="100px" align="center">display 2nd bank</td><td width="100px" align="center">display 3rd bank</td><td width="100px" align="center">display 4th bank</td>
</tr>';
}

$compare = str_replace('[TABLE_ROWS]', $table_rows, $compare);
```

Then call the rest of your code:

```
include_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($compare);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('Compare_Packages.pdf');
```